# Turtlebot 3 Questions

Tags: ros, turtlebot, robotis

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can order a Turtlebot3 Waffle without an SBC or with an alternate SBC, and whether if I substitute the SBC am I now in an unsupported configuration?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273784/turtlebot-3-questions/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2017-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turtlebot3 Burger and Waffle are sold as package so customizing your order will be difficult.
Turtlebot3 is running on the ROS based on Linux, I believe you can use the SBC as long as it supports Linux(Ubuntu 16.04), USB port, Wi-Fi connection.
Please check the operation voltage/power consumption of the SBC as OpenCR might not support power recommendation for a custom SBC.
Please understand that customizing the original package may void the product warranty.

---

Originally posted by [Will Son](https://answers.ros.org/users/32218/will-son/) with karma: 66 on 2017-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0